# How to Access instance Variable of one class to another class in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

[image: this is the code for.m class of first viewcontroller[][1]]I had tried accessing value of IVAR of one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller by making use of property , but i am getting null value.

please let me know how to get value displayd in my secondviewcontroller.

[image]

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: see the pictures that i had attached

Comment: Your code is creating a new instance of the view controller (in which the property value is nil) rather than accessing the existing instance.

Comment: Have a read of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/3985749) and the numerous answers.  They explain very well how to pass data between VCs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: @GurpalRajput You should post your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the right way to get value of property. But you need to make sure `myString` has been assigned a value in `init` method of `ViewController`.

Try in ViewController.m:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.myString = @"My String";
    }

    return self;
}
```

Beside of it, make sure that `myMetod` of SecondViewController is called. If `myMetod` is called, "Print value My String" will be printed.

Comment: i had puted (instance)init on top of viewdidload method of viewcontroller and put code in it , but when i run app after calling of viewdidload nothing happens .. even init method is not calling

Comment: do i need to call init method too in view did load

Comment: You need to make sure that `myMetod` of `SecondViewController` is called. I don't see where you call `myMetod`

Comment: Thanks alot i got it